# Tor not opening certain webpages properly (symfony project?)

Tags: anonymity, web-proxy

Over the past couple of days, I've been having a feeling that some websites do know that I am using Tor. Whenever I try opening certain pages, they either completely refuse to open or simply reload when I do an action like submitting a form.

One example of these sites that is currently making me go crazy is hire writers dot com / signup / writer (sorry for writing it in this format, but I didn't want backlinks to originate from here). When I try opening the page, I get an error. Something about a symfony project.... I believe this site may address something vital about it ( http://dunglas.fr/2013/03/dunglastorcontrolbundle-torcontrol-symfony-integration/)

So in short, I can't have access to the first site mentioned above. I tried out one of the popular proxies... The one from hidemyass , but unfortunately there are some page elements that fail to work. The "antispam slider" for instance does not work and can't be slid across to the right number.

I'm almost out of options but I believe there is something Tor can do for me. I just don't know it yet.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you use Tor with scripts disabled? That may be why some sites won't let you submit forms. At any case, a good amount of clearweb sites block Tor users anyways. Your best bet is to find a proxy that doesn't disable scripts (thats the reason some page elements don't work; many proxies disable scripts by default) or get a VPN.